# handing callbacks from jsonp gives me undefined error

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, jsonp

new to using jsonp.

Been trying for 2 days now trying lots of different things.

i have a web server A that makes an ajax call to web server B.

the api controller method on Web Server B is:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("LoginRequest")]
    public JsonpResult LoginRequest([FromUri]Login login)
    {
        JsonpResult result = new JsonpResult("hello");
        return result;
    }
```

my jquery/ajax is:

```
window.myCallback = function (data) {

    console.log('ok');
};


       var LogIn = {
            Email: $("#txtEmail").val(),
            MobileNo: $("#txtMobileNumber").val(),
            PinCode: '',
            Message: '',
            Success: false
        };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    jsonpCallback: myCallback,
    url: "https://web Server B/api/LoginRequest",
    data: LogIn,
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Success');
        toggleControls(false);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('fail');
    }
```

Setting breakpoints it goes like this:

ajax call is made

code behind is hit

image of watch on the created jsonp object in c#:

[image]

Call back on js is hit (data is undefined)

returning jsonp object is now hit on c# end

error handler in ajax is invoked with error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Answer (score 0):

Either I am stupid or I do not read the examples properly or both but I thought I would point that my error was to put my code in an api controller. As soon as I put it in a normal controller it worked. i would still like to know how to do a cross-browser call to an api controller but for now i am happy it works